# Using a webcrawler to fetch data

Tags: java, python, web-scraping

I would like to create website which quizzes people on animal facts, I could do it manually, but I am wondering how I would go about automating the 'retrieval of facts' from the internet and then inputting it into the quizzes automaticallly. I'm thinking, I could build a web crawler/scraper that collects parts of information from popular sites, and then sends that data to the site, to make the quiz.

How would you go about solving this issue, and if there is a better way of achieving the same think?

PS: I am a beginner, and I might not be using the right terminology

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should take a look at [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/[).

> Scrapy is a fast high-level web crawling and web scraping framework, used to crawl websites and extract structured data from their pages. It can be used for a wide range of purposes, from data mining to monitoring and automated testing.

Here is a nice tutorial page from the documentation: [Scrapy Tutorial](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)

Answer (score -1):

Look up **Selenium**. It is my favorite library for python. It can log into sites, click on certain elements, and you can get data very easily.

Use **pip install selenium** to download

Comment: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/ use this site as a tutorial